# zooming in to vector layer when i click a URL

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a WFS layer in my map. I have buildings in the layer with building_id as an attribute along with other many attributes. I have coordinates too in my layer.

I have a URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:buildings&CQL_FILTER=id='bb21'

How can I use this URL to zoom my map to that building?

Any ideas?

AJ

================updated here ===============

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=genesis:Building_WGS&CQL_FILTER=HOUSE_NO=%271436%27',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var te = new ol.format.GML2();

        var a = te.readFeatures(data)
        var feature = new ol.Feature(a);
        //console.log(test1);
        var geom = feature.get("HOUSE_NO");
        var view = map.getView();
        //view.fit(geom, map.getSize());
        console.log(geom);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to query the url using an ajax request. Many JavaScript libraries support simple ways to make such request, such as jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Then, upon receiving the request response, you'll have to read the result.  If you're using WFS, then your response should be in GML.  OL3 has a format for GML 2 and 3:

- http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.GML2.html
- http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.GML3.html

Both have a `readFeatures` method you can use to transform your response into an array of features, i.e. into instances of `ol.Feature`.  Then you can loop in those features and get their geometry and fit the map to that geometry.

```
var geom = feature.getGeometry();
var view = map.getView();
view.fit(geom, map.getSize());
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the guidance. But I ran into some problem while implementing your solution: I have updated my question with your implemention idea. But When i try to view the features it gives me null. What am I doing wrong? Please see the updated code above.

Comment: gives me "undefined" not null sorry

Comment: `readFeatures`  returns an array of `ol.Feature` objects.  You don't need to create a feature from what it returns.   See the documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.GML3.html#readFeatures.  Also, I suggest you try loading ol-debug.js and put break points using your browser Dev Tool to really understand what's going on.  Do not be afraid to step into the code and see what it does.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean I don't have to create a feature?? Can you write a code sample how to achieve that? I have my code above. What exactly is wrong in my code?

Comment: Look at the documentation of the `readFeatures` method: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.GML3.html#readFeatures.  It returns an array of `ol.Feature` object.  Use your browser Dev Tool to put a break point where you read your features and spy on your `a` variable.  You'll understand.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say but the point is when I use `a` as `ol.Feature` object then I get error message. For example: `a.getId();` I get Error Message: `TypeError: a.getId is not a function`. I would appreciate if you can post a working example here or create Fiddle