# vector source returning empty in source.getFeatures()

Tags: openlayers-3

I have vector layer in my app as following:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  crossOrigin:"Anonymous",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=genesis:Building_WGS&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326'
});


var vector1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});
```

I can see the layer on the map when i run it. But the problem is when i use alert message to check the feature info I see empty. I have a cold like this:

```
alert(vectorSource.getFeatures());
```

can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong here? Any help is accpreciated.

AJ

Comment: Are you sure your wfs request return correct data?

Comment: yes I can see the layer on my map. and it seems like they are in the right position too. can you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Oh sorry don't fully understand what is the problem. Is your problem that vectorSource.getFeatures() returns an empty array?

Comment: yes that is the problem. because i need to access the feature when mouse clicked or something like that.

Comment: When did you do your alert(vectorSource.getFeatures()); ? If you see your data on the map it's nearly  impossible getFeatures returns empty.

Comment: When you try to alert the `vectorSource` isn't fully loaded. This is AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had use the alert() after creating map. But I managed to fix it vector1.getSource().on('change', function(evt){
    var source = evt.target;
    if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
   var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length; 
   console.log("Count after change: " + source.getFeatures());
    }
  });

Comment: Can you help me with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558753/zooming-in-to-vector-layer-when-i-click-a-url

Comment: So, post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't post the solution. this stackoverlflow prevents me from doing that. That is why I posted as comment above

Answer (score 10):

You've already reached a solution, so to register the solution.

When you pass an `url` param, [`ol.source.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) is asynchronously (AJAX) loaded so you have to wait until it's fully loaded with:

```
vectorSource.on('change', function(evt){
    var source=evt.target;
    if(source.getState() === 'ready'){
        console.info(vectorSource.getFeatures());
    }
});
```

Comment: As I have already mentioned in my comment above that I have reached the sloution with what you have mentioned here. Can you help me with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558753/zooming-in-to-vector-layer-when-i-click-a-url/32565168?noredirect=1#comment53024643_32565168